# How to restore a previous document version via client-side API?

Tags: document-library, rest, web-services, spservices

Is there a way to restore a previous version of a document, using client-side code?  I've been looking at the REST API, Lists Web Service, and SPServices JS library, but couldn't find any methods for restoring previous document versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below sample code that uses the restoreByLabel method to restore the previous version of the document.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',restoreFile);
});
var oFile;
function restoreFile() {
 //Get client context and web
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
//Get File object and restore a specific version
oFile=oWeb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Playground/Demo
 Library/Document.docx');
oFile.get_versions().restoreByLabel("6.0");

//Load Client Context and execute the batch
clientContext.load(oFile);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
}
function QuerySuccess() {
//Get major version
var majorVersion =oFile.get_majorVersion();
   console.log("Version Restored . New Major Version - "+ majorVersion );
 } 

function QueryFailure(sender,args) {
   console.log('Request failed - '+args.get_message());
 }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried this using CSOM, but it seems [`FileVersionCollection.RestoreByLabel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fileversioncollection.restorebylabel.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this in a SharePoint environment, but in OneDrive there are endpoints to deal with versioning. As OneDrive and SharePoint tend to work with similar REST calls, you might give these a go.

To restore a previous version:

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/versions/{version-id}/restoreVersion

POST /sites/{site-id}/items/{item-id}/versions/{version-id}/restoreVersion
```

Get the versions of an item:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/items/{item-id}/versions

GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/versions
```

For more details see:

- [REST restore @ OneDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitemversion_restore)
- [REST versions @ OneDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitemversion_restore)

Answer (score 0):

using the REST api in SharePoint,
post to the following endpoint with an empty request body...

```
/site/_api/web/lists/getbyid(DocumentLibraryId)/Items(ItemId)/File/Versions/restoreByLabel(VersionLabel)
```