# How I can programmatically backup a site by Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, rest, administration, sharepoint-rest-api

I know how to backup and restore by SP powershell and by server object model.

by powershell

```
Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

[by server object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc264319(v=office.14).aspx)

```
SPSiteCollection mySiteCols = myApp.Sites;
mySiteCols.Backup(@"http://Server/sites/MySiteCollection", @"\\OtherServer\WSSBackups\SiteCollections\BackupOfMySiteCollection", true);
```

Now I try to figure out if I can backup the whole site by SharePoint Rest Api or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As short answer,** No, there is no REST endpoint for backup and restore.

For more details Check [REST API reference and samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)

**The workarounds are**

- To develop your own web service and host it on your SharePoint server and consume it at your application.
- Use Server Side Object Model - C# (As you have mentioned)
- Use PowerShell (As you have mentioned)

Comment: But, I've found [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/222518/56779) about restoring by label. Do you know what also can be restored by rest api ?

Comment: This bro for restore document version, not site :)